# Magnitude Of Difference Vectors

Tags: vectors, displacement

According to a text I am reading, the magnitude of difference vectors is $\vec C = \vec S - \vec T$. With the displacement vectors $\vec S$ and $\vec T$ having magnitudes $||S||=3m$ and $||T||=4m$ respectively. And by following the rules just previously stated,the magnitude of the difference vectors is $||C|| = 3m-4m =-1m$

But is this valid? I thought that a magnitude can not be negative? Could the $-1$ indicate the direction of the vector? Or am I supposed to ignore the negative value and simply take the absolute value of $|-1|$ to be $1$?

The text says there may be more than one right answer to this problem, so if anyone could show the various "correct" answers that would help.

Comment: Try to think about the maximum and minimum of the vector addition (included substraction) and also imagine about two concentric circles.
You will not get a negative result for a vector $\textbf{C}$

Comment: You can not add/subtract vectors like that. They follow the paralellogram or the triangle law. If I give you two sides of a Triangle as 4m and 3m, would you say that the third side is 7m or would you worry about the orientation of the sides with respect to one another?

Comment: C seems to be the vector that points from T to S. Calling it magnitude feels like a typical bizarre "simplification" that messes up all logical thinking. Just ignore the name and take the normal of the "magnitude vector". Which is not the formula you posted, since S and T as written are just the normals of the vectors (when they have arrows you need to express them wrt a basis). (With normal I meant ||•||)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule for a norm associated to a scalar product is
$$||\vec C||^2 = ||\vec S - \vec T||^2 = (\vec S - \vec T)\cdot (\vec S - \vec T) = ||\vec S||^2-2\vec S\cdot \vec T+||\vec T||^2,$$
so here
$$||\vec C||^2 = 25m^2-2\vec S\cdot \vec T.$$
From Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $|\vec S\cdot \vec T| \leq ||\vec S||||\vec T||=12m^2$ you get
$$||\vec C||^2 \geq25m^2-24m^2=m^2,$$
hence
$$||\vec C|| \geq m.$$
The same Cauchy-Schwartz inequality leads also to
$$||\vec C|| \leq 7m.$$
Both extreme cases correspond to colinear vectors (that is, parallel or anti-parallel).

Comment: Can you show how the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality leads to the magnitude of vector C to be less than or equal to 7m?

Comment: Yes: $||\vec C||^2 = 25m^2 - 2  \vec S \cdot \vec T \leq  25m^2 + 2  |\vec S \cdot \vec T| \leq  25m^2 + 24m^2$ (note that the sign of $\vec S \cdot \vec T$ is arbitrary).